# how to describe a recursion in an non static method. Now the recursion is not working

Tags: java, recursion, methods, binary-tree, non-static

I want to go through a binary tree recursive in the method public void inorder(). Afterwards I want to give out all the values which are in the binary tree. But in my case the recursive process does not work.Can somebody help?

I tried to do the recursive process with a static method but of course it is not working. I do not know how can I write the recursive process different from a static method recursive method. That is may problem. Can somebody help?

```
class BinaryNode {
    private BinaryNode leftSon, rightSon;
    private int value;

    public BinaryNode(int v) {
        value = v;
    }

    public boolean contains(int v) { 
        if ( ( leftSon != null) & ( rightSon != null) )
        if ( v == value ) return true;
        else
            if ( v < value ) leftSon.contains( v ) ;
            else rightSon.contains( v );
        return false;
    }

    public void insert(int v) { 
        if ( v != value ) {
            if ( v < value ) {
                BinaryNode links = new BinaryNode( v );
            }  
        } else {
            BinaryNode rechts = new BinaryNode( v );
        }  
    }

    public void inorder() { 
        if ( leftSon != null ) { inorder( ) ; }
        System.out.println( value );
        if ( rightSon != null ) { inorder( ) ; }
        System.out.println( value );
    }
}
```

Comment: I'd expect the recursive calls within `inorder` to use the value you're checking against, e.g. `leftSon.inorder()` and `rightson.inorder()` - like you do for `contains`. (I'd also strongly suggest you adopt a more conventional formatting style, and rename `inorder` to `inOrder` or even `printInOrder`...)

Comment: Please describe what "does not work."  What values do you get, and what did you expect to get?  Can you provide code that calls this code with sample input that shows us the error?  (In `inorder()`, you print the `value` twice.  That can't be what you want.  Print once.)